# How can I stop Jquery (Ajax) from looping data (Includes PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically, I've scripted a script inside of my **index.php** file which gets messages from the database by calling a php file and returning the data from the database. **However!** It's looping like 2-3 and sometimes 9 more times!

Is anyone able to help me with my query! Thank you, sorry for my English

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var flag = 0;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "assets/js/ajax/messages.php",
                data: {
                    'offset': 0,
                    'limit': 6,
                    'user_id': <?php echo $User->Id(); ?>
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#messages').append(data);
                    flag += 3;
                }
            });

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "assets/js/ajax/messages.php",
                        data: {
                            'offset': flag,
                            'limit': 3,
                            'user_id': <?php echo $User->Id(); ?>
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#messages').append(data);
                            flag += 3;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You're issue is probably because of the scroll event, which fires a ton.  You will probably want to look into throttling or debouncing that logic.

Comment: Hello @Taplar, could you go into a little more detail on what you mean? Thank you so much for the reply!

Comment: Pop a `console.log('hi!'+ Date.now())` inside your scroll event handler as the first thing it does, open your console, and run your script.  Watch how many times that runs when you scroll.

Comment: See https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/

Comment: @Taplar, literally added that under the ` if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                        console.log('hi!'+ Date.now())` and it spammed the whole log just going down like 45px;

Comment: Yep.  So if you put it inside the if statement, rather than above it, that's how many ajax requests it is starting.  Take a look at that link Wesley Smith shared which includes some details about throttling and debouncing

Comment: Ah okay, will do I'll check it out now:

Comment: I looked at that article I don't understand how that would help, e.g.tbe problem I'm having is that I scroll down and more rows duplicate but I'm not quite sure what to do 